# first_or_initialize create only one object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have problem with rails first_or_initialize method. I have model Localization which has_many OpeningHours. In my model Localization i have code:

```
has_many :opening_hours
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :opening_hours, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['from_time'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  after_initialize :build_opening_hours

  def build_opening_hours
    if self.new_record? 
      self.opening_hours.first_or_initialize(day: "monday", from_time: nil, to_time: nil)
      self.opening_hours.first_or_initialize(day: "tuesday", from_time: nil, to_time: nil)
    end
  end
```

And the problem is that this build_opening_hours method initialize only object with day: "monday" the second object with day: "tuesday" is not initializing. What's wrong? I can't figure why is that...

Comment: No one knows the answer? It's very important for me. Please help...

Comment: How you are verifying that it is initializing only first object i.e. record with day as 'monday'?

Comment: Mateusz, associations are identifying by `association_id` key. So, if you want to fetch resource.opening_hours, you'll get nothing because of your new resource record haven't id.

Please provide a model and your aim, I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everyone that try to help me. I have model Localization:

```
class Localization < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :opening_hours
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :opening_hours, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['from_time'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  after_initialize :build_opening_hours

  def build_opening_hours
    if self.new_record? 
      self.opening_hours.first_or_initialize(day: "monday", from_time: nil, to_time: nil)
      self.opening_hours.first_or_initialize(day: "tuesday", from_time: nil, to_time: nil)
    end
  end
end
```

This model has many opening_hours. My model opening_hours looks like this:

```
class OpeningHour < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :localization
validates :to_time, :from_time, presence: true
end
```

And now my goal is when i try to create new localization to have 7 opening_hours object associated with this localization, for example: "monday", "tuesday" etc.
My form for creating new localization looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:partners, @localization] do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :address
  = f.input :city
  = f.input :zip_code
  = f.input :phone_in_hours
  = f.input :phone_after_hours
  = f.input :email 
  = f.input :email2
  = f.input :substitution_cost_in_hours
  = f.input :return_cost_in_hours
  #checkbox
    = check_box_tag 'after_hours_checkbox', 1, true
    %b= t('localizations.after_hours')
  .disabled
    = f.input :return_cost_after_hours
    = f.input :substitution_cost_after_hours
    = f.input :information
    %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered#localizations
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Czynne
          %th Dzień tygodnia
          %th Otwarte od
          %th Otwarte do 
      %tbody
        = f.simple_fields_for :opening_hours do |t|
          %tr    
            %td
            %td
              = t.input :day
            %td
              = t.input :from_time, as: :string, :input_html => { :class => 'from_time' } 
            %td
              = t.input :to_time, as: :string, :input_html => { :class => 'to_time' } 

  = f.submit t('localizations.add'), class: "btn btn-primary"
```